# Are both electrons and holes responsible for conductivity in an extrinsic semiconductor (both n-type and p-type)?

Tags: semiconductors

In a semiconductor, the drift velocity Vd and E(electric field intensity) are directly proportional to each other.. with the proportionality constant as mobility of charge carriers.. in the formula I studied in the textbook they substituted this mobility as the sum of the products of the concentration of the holes with their mobility and electrons with their mobility..so the doubt..

Comment: This question could be improved by proper formatting (less .., more new lines) and quoting the actual formulas (use of MathJax is highly recommended to properly present formulas).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, electrical conductivity is a function of both electron and hole concentrations, in all semiconductors, intrinsic or extrinsic.

$$\sigma=\mu_nn+\mu_pp$$

However, since the electron and hole concentrations have an inverse relationship, unless your semiconductor is very lightly doped or intrinsic, the vast majority of conductivity will be from either electrons or holes, whichever has the higher concentration, the majority carriers.